# Using loaded .raw image data as a IDirect3DTexture9 texture in DirectX9?

Tags: directx, directx-9

Im trying to make use of a simple .raw loader as an easy way to load images into a program to be used as textures by DirectX9.

I have a problem in that the D3DX functions are not available to me at all, nor can i find them anywhere. I have constructed my own matrix routines fine, but can't use the D3DX Texture file function without some pointers.

I've done my homework, so i'm thinking what i need is to use the CreateTexture function and some code to marry my unsigned char image with IDirect3DTexture9 *DXTexture.

```
IDirect3DTexture9 *DXTexture;

unsigned char texture;
loadRawImage(&texture, "tex", 128, 128);

g_pD3DDevice->CreateTexture(128,128,0,D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC,D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,
                                               D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &DXTexture,NULL);

//code required here to marry my unsigned char image with DXTexture

g_pD3DDevice->SetTexture(0, texture);
```

I've seen this page, looks sort of like what i need..

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/567044-problem-loading-image-data-into-idirect3dtexture9/

```
IDirect3DTexture9* tempTexture = 0;
HRESULT hr = device->CreateTexture(this->width,this,>height,0,D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC,
                                D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&tempTexture,0);

//assignment pointer
D3DCOLOR *Ptr;
unsigned char *tempPtr = 0; // increment pointer
int count = 0; //index into color data


//lock texture and get ptr
D3DLOCKED_RECT rect;
hr = tempTexture->LockRect(0,&rect,0,D3DLOCK_DISCARD);
tempPtr = (unsigned char*)rect.pBits; // assign to unsigned char 
                                          // pointer to make pointer arithmetic 
                                          // smooth
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->height; i++)
{

    tempPtr += rect.Pitch;  //move to next line in texture
    Ptr = (D3DCOLOR*)tempPtr;
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < this->width; j++)
    {
        Ptr[j] = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(this->imageData[count++],
                                           this->imageData[count++],
                                           this->imageData[count++]);
    }

}


tempTexture->UnlockRect(0);
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. This is for a small demo so code is being kept down to a minimum.

EDIT to respond to drop

Basically my question is how can I use the loaded .raw image data as a DirectX9 texture? I know there must be some internal byte format in which IDirectTexture9 textures are arranged, I just need some pointers on how to convert my data to this format.This is without using D3DX functions.

Comment: Looks good. So, what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try using below approach

```
   D3DLOCKED_RECT rect;
   ppTexture->LockRect( 0, &rect, 0, D3DLOCK_DISCARD );
   unsigned char* dest = static_cast<unsigned char*>(rect.pBits);
   memcpy(dest, &pBitmapData[0], sizeof(unsigned char) * biWidth * biHeight * 4);
   ppTexture->UnlockRect(0);
```